# Reconcile multiple versions of an Access table

Tags: microsoft-access

An access mdb file has bounced around between several computers, and old versions of the file have been used on some computers while the copies were being used on other computers. This has resulted in different versions of the same mdb that need to be reconciled, and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm actually only concerned with one table in the db. I'll call it tblA. (It has an autonumbered pk.) The structure of the table is the same in all versions. I'm trying to gather all the copies of tblA and generate one version that contains only unique records.

The db lived on one pc for a long time, so all copies have the initial records in common. I tried to take advantage of this by finding the pk of the last record that is common to all versions and then copying all records after that one to a new table. However, because of how it was incorrectly copied around (sometimes back to the original computer) and reused, the records after those initial ones may or may not be found in other versions too.

I thought of using INSERT INTO along with a subquery containing UNION, but I got an error saying that the UNION cannot be used in a subquery.  This works

`SELECT field1
FROM table1
UNION SELECT field1
FROM table2;`

This is what gave me the error "operation is not allowed in subqueries":

`INSERT INTO tblMyNewTable (field1) from (
SELECT field1
FROM table1
UNION SELECT field1
FROM table2;
)`

Obviously, nothing else has worked either.

Thanks again!

Comment: What exactly are you asking for, help with combining tables or resolving why the `INSERT INTO` didn't work. Please [edit] your question to include what you've researched and the details of the query you attempted.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question....

http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/208819

Comment: It won't let me select this as the answer... but it is.